# Maven exclude directory from compiling and running under tests

Tags: maven-2, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to set up my first maven project for my code which can be found here:
https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib

I have 3 pom files:

1. https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/pom.xml
2. https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/jorlib-core/pom.xml
3. https://github.com/jkinable/jorlib/blob/master/jorlib-demo/pom.xml

I would like to **exclude** all files in the following directory from both compilation and testing:

```
jorlib-core/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp
```

Note the "**test**" part. According to this [website](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/150334/exclude-source-files-while-compilingrunning-jira-plugin.-atlas-compile-atlas-run-) I can use the maven-compiler-plugin together with excludes and testExcludes for that. So I've added the plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3</version>
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**</exclude>
      <exclude>**/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/Master.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/TSPMasterData.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/ExactPricingProblemSolver.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/cuts/SubtourInequalityGenerator.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/cuts/SubtourInequalityGenerator.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/**test**/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/**test**/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/**test**/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <testExcludes>
      <exclude>**/frameworks/**</exclude>
      <exclude>**/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**</exclude>
      <exclude>**/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>/org/jorlib/frameworks/**</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/Master.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/TSPMasterData.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/ExactPricingProblemSolver.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/cuts/SubtourInequalityGenerator.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/cg/master/cuts/SubtourInequalityGenerator.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/**test**/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**/*</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/**test**/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**</exclude>
      <exclude>**/src/**test**/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/*</exclude>
    </testExcludes>
</configuration>
```

I've tried a huge number of exclude rules (the above are just a small subset). I run "mvn clean; mvn test" but still I keep getting compile errors on classes within

```
jorlib-core/src/test/java/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp
```

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution appears to be simple. The following code suffices (notice the sue of testExcludes):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <testExcludes>
          <exclude>**/org/jorlib/frameworks/columnGeneration/tsp/**/*</exclude>
        </testExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This didn't work for me because somewhere else in my code I had a lonely import statement which imported a file from the directory I wanted to exclude. Albeit this particular file wasn't used at all (I just forgot to delete the import statement), the import statement alone caused maven to compile the excluded directory anyway. Makes me wonder why maven doesn't detect this 'clash'? Nevertheless I'm happy to report that my problem is solved.